# What are these git dot un files?

Tags: git, vim

In my git repo, the results of `ls -a` is:

```
.fileInFirstCommit.un~  
.fileInSecondCommit.un~ 
.git                    
fileInFirstCommit       
fileInFirstCommit~      
fileInSecondCommit      
fileInSecondCommit~
```

what are all these .un~ files?

Comment: Seems like some kind of backup files generated by your text editor(s), not the git itself. Please check the contents of those files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are Vim's `undofiles`. `undofile` is a relatively new feature that allows you to store undo history for individual files. [This blog post](http://amix.dk/blog/post/19548) covers the basic idea pretty well. See also `:help new-persistent-undo` in Vim.